# Making chart grids be finer grained

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

For the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{bchart}


\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols,automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
scaled y ticks = true,
width=1*\textwidth,
height=8cm,
xlabel={Query},
ylabel={Elapsed Time (in seconds)},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
zmajorgrids,
enlarge x limits=0,
scaled x ticks = true]
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
line width=1.0pt
]
coordinates{
(0,10)
(1,4)
(2,5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Blah}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can I make the grids finer grained ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to define the style for each axis grid. `grid=major` sets all of them at once. Also you need to introduce minor ticks to get finer grid then you can use `grid=both` which means `minor` and `major`. If the following is not enough you can do the same for the `y` axis or `minor tick` option.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{tikz,pgf} %Pgfplots loads TikZ, and TikZ loads PGF by default



\usepackage{pgfplots}
%================================  You don't need all this for the MWE
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{bchart}


\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols,automata}
%%=================================
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
scaled y ticks = true,
width=\textwidth,
height=8cm,
xlabel={Query},
ylabel={Elapsed Time (in seconds)},
grid=both,
ticks=both,
minor xtick={0,0.1,...,2},
enlarge x limits=0,
scaled x ticks = true
]
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
line width=1.0pt
]
coordinates{
(0,10)
(1,4)
(2,5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Blah}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of saying `minor x tick={0,0.1,...,2}`, you can also say `minor x tick num=1`, which will put one minor tick between each pair of major ticks. This has the advantage of not drawing the grid lines at the major tick positions twice, and you don't need to worry about adjusting the minor tick range if you change the axis range.

Comment: @Cemre  Jake is right! I keep on forgetting that option.